# find the first node in path not having relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have relationships and nodes like this

```
(x:Execution)-[:with]->(first:Param)->[:with]-(second:Param)-...[:with]->(last:Param)
```

Here (Param) can be any number of times and (Execution) is optional and may be missing. I need to find all such (first:Param) where (Execution) is missing.

Can anyone help me write Neo4j Cypher query for this?

Answer (score 1):

If this can be accurately described as a :Param node with no incoming :with relationship, you can use this to find your nodes:

```
MATCH (first:Param)
WHERE NOT ()-[:with]->(first)
RETURN first
```